# Erlang Output to text file

Tags: windows, erlang

I am new to Erlang and I am trying to find an easy way to output Erlang command results to a test file in Windows command line. This is what I tried so far:

```
c:\Windows\Temp>erl example.erl "main" -e > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if its a small script perhaps you can use escript as described in [here](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html)

> escript provides support for running short Erlang programs without
>   having to compile them first and an easy way to retrieve the command
>   line arguments

then you can get what you want to work the way you want

```
escript myfunctions_tests > output.txt
```